# Is this c++ inheritance structure possible?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have not programmed in c++ in a long time and want some simple behavior that no amount of virtual keywords has yet to produce:

```
class Base {
  public:
    int both() { return a(); }
};

class Derived : public Base {
  protected:
    int a();
};

class Problem : public Derived {
};

Problem* p = new Problem();
p.both();
```

Which gives me a compile-time error. Is this sort of behavior possible with c++? Do I just need forward declaration? Virtual keywords on everything?

Comment: You should add the compile-time error.

Comment: `both` needs to be public, but also there's no `a()` in `Base`...

Comment: Have you come from a C# or Java background? If you have you may wish to read up on some of the basics of C++. C++ does things quite a bit differently than C# or Java does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You will have to use a pure virtual `a` in `base`.

```
class Base {
    virtual int a() = 0;
    int both() {
        return a();
    }
};
```

Comment: Technically it doesn't have to be pure virtual. It merely has to be virtual. The OP never specified whether he wanted his `Base` class to be an *abstract* base class. You can just as easily provide some default behavior in the `Base` class and make it overrideable using `viurtal`.

Answer (score 4):

You should declare the `a()` function as a pure virtual method in the `Base` class.

```
class Base {
    int both() {
        return a();
    }

    virtual int a()=0;
};
```

Then implement the `a()` method in the `Derived` class

```
class Derived : public Base {
    int a(){/*some code here*/}
};
```

And finally, `Problem` class doesn't see the `both()` method, since its private in `Base`. Make it `public`.

```
class Base {
public:
    int both() {
        return a();
    }
};
```

Comment: + remember to make both public.

Answer (score 3):

Your function `both()` is private by default. Try:

```
class Base {
public:
    int both() {
        // ...
```

<sup>(In the future, it would be helpful if you tell us what the actual error message was.)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You need `a()` to be declared in `class Base`, otherwise the compiler doesn't know what to do with it.

Also, `both()` is currently a private method (that's the default for classes), and should be made public in order to call it from `main`.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems in your code :

- unless you declare them public or protected, elements of a class are private as a default.
- you need a virtual keyword to define a virtual function that would be callable in a parent.
- new returns a pointer to Problem.

Here's a complete working code based on your test :

```
class Base { 
protected:
virtual int a()=0;
public:
    int both() { 
        return a(); 
    } 
}; 

class Derived : public Base { 
private :
int a()
{
printf("passing through a!");
return 0;
}


}; 

class Problem : public Derived { 
}; 

int main(void)
{
  Problem* p = new Problem(); 
  p->both();
}
```

tested on [CodePad](http://codepad.org/of4rxkTS).

Answer (score 1):

As others point out, you need to declare `a()` as pure virtual method of `Base` and change access to public to make your snippet work.

Here is another approach possible in c++: instead of virtual functions, you can use static polymorphism via the [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
template <class D>
class Base : public D
{
public: 
    int both() { return D::a(); }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> 
{
public:
    int a();
};
```

I'm posting this approach since you're asking what is *possible* in c++. In practice, virtual methods are most often a better choice because of their flexibility.